# How to add a mp3 file in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, save, ios-simulator, mp3

I can add images, videos in iOS simulator by dragging them into the window and those are saved in simulator **photos** app. But when a mp3 file is dragged on it can be played in **Safari** but there is no option of saving it.

Is there any way to save a mp3 file so that later I can pick the file from an app?

Answer (score 2):

It's still not allowed to drag and drop and save mp3 to iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Its not supported in iphone simulator.We have to drag the music files into our project.then we can access from it.Refer this [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21431-how-to-get-music-in-iphone-simulator.html) also